# How to disable google SSL in opera?

Tags: browser, ssl, opera

I want to use Google in Opera in normal `http` to speed up search; how can I disable Google SSL in opera?

Comment: Nowadays there's no noticeable speed difference between http: and https:

Comment: @JanDoggen but in my opera,speed reduced;my internet connection is not pretty fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Opera version do you currently use?

If it's Opera 12, make sure you are not logged in to any Google account and type http://www.google.com directly. Just in case,  clear cookies and caches before or use private browsing. Works for every Opera 12 install I encountered.

If it's Chromium based Opera 15, I'm afraid it has become harder to use HTTP because by design Chromium based browser abides the preloaded HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) database. Google.com including most of its subdomains are included in that database. 
(see http://dev.chromium.org/sts)

Chromium actually has a way to bypass this via *about://net-internals/#hsts*, unfortunately this is either disabled or not available on Opera 15.